# Find out your cognito role in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

How do you find out your Amazon Cognito role while running objective-c ios code in debug. I want to see it in NSLog. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using the 'old authentication flow', which would involve passing roles to your constructor, the client doesn't know which role is being assumed. The service has the roles associated to your pool and makes that decision for you.

You can either try to check by seeing if you've used an identity provider, which would mean the auth role, or you could move from the new flow back to the old one.

[This docs page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html) goes into a bit more detail on the old and new flows.

Comment: I understand and having it working for developer identities. I just need to figure out a way to keep the user logged in and authenticated to have full access to the db.